# How to mask column(s) from an ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

`enter code here`I have a `numpy` `ndarray`, called `pte`, like this:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[1.000000e+00 9.630769e-01 4.302222e-02 8.238154e-02]
 [2.000000e+00 7.661538e-01 3.153453e-01 4.497161e-01]
 [3.000000e+00 5.753846e-01 6.559556e-01 8.274414e-01]
 [4.000000e+00 4.027350e-01 9.705709e-01 1.175706e+00]
 ...
]
```

How do I mask columns so that they are removed from the `ndarray`?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
mask = np.ones(len(pte), dtype=bool)
mask[[0]] = False
arr = pte[mask]
```

I would like `arr` to look like:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[9.630769e-01 4.302222e-02 8.238154e-02]
 [7.661538e-01 3.153453e-01 4.497161e-01]
 [5.753846e-01 6.559556e-01 8.274414e-01]
 [4.027350e-01 9.705709e-01 1.175706e+00]
 ...
]
```

In other words, all the values of column zero are deleted.

Comment: I am not sure where you are referring. Do you mean mask[:, 1:] = False. If so, I tried several iterations of this and arr is the same as pte. No column gets dropped.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `pte[:, 1:]`

Comment: Ah yes that works. Thanks. Although, that is not a mask!